# Innodb errors - considering changing to aria

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

On my local machine, using XAMPP, my MySQL would intermittently not start. I have followed lots of solutions for this, and the innodb_force_recovery=1 usually fixes it, at least for a while.

It is very annoying though, and I have been unable to find a permanent solution. I am therefore considering changing my storage engine to Aria, which is, as you know, MariaDB's enhancement for MyISAM.

**My question:** are there any reasons, for "general use" databases, why I SHOULD NOT do that?

**Edit:** I am aware of the differences of row-level locking and table-level locking, as well as that there is no transactions support. Any other reasons?

Comment: I would go for MariaDB or Percona - try XtraDB? AriaDB might be interesting - haven't heard much about it. You might be better off finding out the reasons for your regular failures - there's a reason InnoDB is **by far** the most popular engine.

Comment: Not only is InnoDB the most popular, Oracle is pouring huge amounts of effort into it, and deprecating everything else.  MariaDB is downstream and picks up those InnoDB improvements while working on their relatively new Aria engine.  Please supply more details on the InnoDB errors; that should _not_ be happening.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. I have since exported all my databases and reinstalled my local dev environment, so I can't reproduce the errors at this point.